# Form Submit success response using servlets

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am submitting a form for file upload to a servlet but I don't know how to send a success event back to Javascript. I need to call a function after the servlet is successfully executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just let the Servlet set a variable in request scope and let JSP generate the JavaScript code accordingly.

Servlet:

```
boolean success = true; // or false.
request.setAttribute("success", success);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

JSP:

```
<script>var success = ${success};</script>
```

It will end up in webbrowser like

```
<script>var success = true;</script>
```

You know how to continue with this JavaScript, right? `if (success) {} else {}` and so on :)

#### See also:

- [Communication between Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) - explains the concepts in depth.

Comment: I dont want to change the page by using requestDispatcher

Comment: It isn't changing the page. It is just **displaying** the JSP page associated with the request. A redirect is changing the request. I don't see where this aversion is coming from. Your *actual* problem lies now somewhere else. If you elaborate *why* you don't want to use the dispatcher, then we can suggest different approaches.